# How to extract JSON data in react native V5

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am trying to extract  JSON data  which I am doing using the POST request in react native can somebody let me know how to do that
and I want to pass the extracted data to another screen as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting any data by POST method then you must have to use GET method to extract the data. You can use **axios** for it like

```
`axios.get('endpoint').then(res => res.json)`
```

After getting your data you can store it in some state and then you have to pass the data to other screens like below:

```
 onPress={() => {
                          this.props.navigation.navigate('YourScreenName', {
                            data: item.data,
                          });
                        }}
```

Comment: I did that its is giving me an undefined object (evaluating route.params)

Comment: get route params of data like this in your that screen.....
  
const {data} = route.params;      

And accept the answer if that resolves your problem